# how do I get the data and store it in the variable using anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

this is my objective:

```
y="<3";
let str = () => {
  if(y.length==2){
    return y[1];
  }
}

console.log(str);
```

I want to store the string value '3' in **str** variable. How do I do that?

Comment: `str` is a function, it can't be a function and store the string `3`. What your asking for doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I *think* you actually want `console.log(str());` but be aware the value `3` IS NOT stored in `str`

Comment: just wrap the function in parenthesis and execute it right away
`(() => {
  if(y.length==2){
    return y[1];
  }
})()`

Comment: Ask yourself some general things 
Why do you need a anonymous function?
Where do you want to save your substring with the value 3, because you can't store it in a function?
Is it possible, that `y` contains a dynamic value?
How do you want to process the value 3?
If you only want to console.log a 3 if the text's length is 2 why do you need an anonymous function?
This snippet and your question does not show clearly what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You created a function but never actually "called" it, do `console.log(str());` instead of `console.log(str);`
this will print the result of the `str()` function